# Como pegar os valores de latitude e longitude do exemplo de Autocomplete do Google Mapas?

Tags: php, javascript, html5, laravel

Estou usando este exemplo no formulário do Lavarel: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform?hl=pt-br

Funciona bem, faço o autocomplete dos campos, mas queria auto completar com um input tipo hidden a latitude e longitude.

Como posso pegar a latitude e longitude, utilizando este exemplo do link, e colocando num input hidden para armazenar em meu banco de dados estes dois dados?

No meu formulário, estou tentando pegar desta forma:

```
 <tr>
                            <td class="field-label"><b>Latitude</b></td>
                            <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
                                <input required class="field" name="latitude" id="lat" disabled="true"></input>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: No `callback` da função `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` você obtêm a latitude e longitude, aí é só atribuir para os `input`s.

Comment: Tentei no id= mas não pegou...

Comment: Posta o código, que você usou, aqui para podermos te auxiliar.

Comment: @lucas editei a pergunta com o trecho do HTML no final...

Comment: Ramos, por gentileza, na pergunta, insira também o código `javascript`.